# Delphi Creating XML file

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

I am relatively new to programming but with the help of Google i'm getting on well.

I need some help with a program I am writing and I have a small problem with the coding. It does everything I want it to except I can't work out 1 part.

What I am trying to achieve is an XML file with a line that looks like:

```
<Entry Line='  Play &quot;Mains_Fail&quot;' />
```

However the code I am using in Delphi:

```
Parameter.AddChild('Entry').Attributes['line'] := '  Play "Mains_Fail" ';
```

Produces the following line in XML:

```
<Entry Line="  Play &quot;Mains_Fail&quot;" />
```

This doesn't work on the system reading the file as i need the apostrophe in the XML output not quotes.

With what code can I produce apostrophe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Entry Line="  Play &quot;Mains_Fail&quot;" />
```

This is perfectly correct, and is semantically identical to

```
<Entry Line='  Play "Mains_Fail"' />
```

or

```
<Entry Line='  Play &quot;Mains_Fail&quot;' />
```

Attribute values are quoted, either single or double quotes. If you use single quotes, then any single quote characters in the value must be escaped, with `&apos;`. If you use double quotes, then any double quote characters in the value must be escaped, with `&quot;`.

The bottom line is that you are producing XML, and any XML parser will read all three of the above snippets identically. If you have a system that won't read one of these snippets then you should replace the parser with an actual XML parser.